# Angular - How to pass object dynamically to div element using [ngstyle]

Tags: html, css, angular, css-grid, ng-style

I'm trying to make grid-row and grid-column to be dynamically populated from API.

component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let element of elements">
   <div [ngStyle]="styleObject(element.Row,element.Column)">{{element['Tool Name']}}</div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
styleObject(row : String,Column:String): Object {
    let obj :Object;
    obj = {'grid-row':''+Number(row),'grid-column':''+Number(Column)};
    console.log(obj);
    return obj.toString;
}
```

This way in the console it is printing but it's not reflecting in UI. [Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfCXE.png)

It worked properly when I tried to populate the data manually as

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'grid-column':'9','grid-row':'9'}">{{element['Tool Name']}}</div>
```

In the Inspect Element mode, the attribute is showing as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvmaW.png)

Where am I making mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return `obj` instead of `obj.toString`. You need to pass key-value pair to `[ngStyle]`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#description

Comment: No Luck sir, tried it by sending obj as well

Comment: Note (plus the answer) you can also use binding over style.grid-column/row: `<div [style.grid-row]="element.Row" [style.grid-column]="element.Column">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`NgStyle` docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#description),

> Set a collection of style values using an expression that returns key-value pairs.

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
```

You need to return `styleObject` as **key-value pair** type instead of `string` type.

```js
styleObject(row : String, Column:String): Object {
  let obj :Object;
  obj = {'grid-row':''+Number(row),'grid-column':''+Number(Column)};
  return obj;
}
```

You may check out this [sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-11kcw1).

---

### Updated for grid layout issue

For your grid layout, should have `.grid-container` and `.grid-item`.

`.grid-container`

> Wrap the whole `div` element and turn it to the grid.

`.grid-item`

> The grid item with `[ngStyle]` have to place here so that it will be positioned based on `grid-row` and `grid-column`.

---

> component.html

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div *ngFor="let element of elements" class="grid-item" 
    [ngStyle]="styleObject(element.row, element.column)">
    {{element['name']}}
  </div>
</div>
```

> .component.css

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Sample Grid Layout on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tghekz)

Comment: It's not working with grid-row somehow sir, I tried with background-color it's working properly.

Comment: Hi, check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uehf9u), suspect is your CSS styling issue. Make sure the items are wrapped in `.grid-container` element.

Comment: Hello, I have changed the order of elements in the component.ts file from the above demo. The issue still exists. This is the forked demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hn4ofq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi @Roddamharshavardhanreddy, sorry for late response. I had updated the answer. The `[ngStyle]` need to place in the `.grid-item` element.